# Uncaught Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11 in Chrome

Tags: jquery

Following code give me `Uncaught Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11 error.` Only in crome.

```
ondblclick="$(this).hide();$('#edit_attachment').val($(this).val()).show();$('#a-info').show();"/>
```

Comment: Can you debug it by removing one stmt a time to find out which stmt is throwing the error

Comment: I debug it. This line throwing the error. $('#edit_attachment').val($(this).val());

Comment: what is `edit_attachment`?

Comment: Thanks Arun P Johny, I have resolved it

Comment: Actually #edit_attachment is a id of input type file, and i was trying  to insert value into input type file from a textbox. I was calling dbclick() on method on textbox As- $('#edit_attachment').val($(this).val());

Comment: You could convert the last comment to an answer of your own question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed by-

Actually `#edit_attachment` is an id of input type file, and i was trying to insert value into input type file from a textbox. I was calling `dbclick()` on method on textbox As- `$('#edit_attachment').val($(this).val());`